# Есть ли в node.js что-то наподобие input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, input

Мне нужно запросить строковые данные у пользователя, которые затем будут помещены в глобальную переменную для дальнейшей работы с ней. Как это реализуется?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно прям взаимодействовать в форме диалога через консоль , как вариант запускать приложение с аргументами  (например node test.js hello=world)  и при старте приложения считывать параметры и сохранять

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

let GlobalAnswer = 'nothing';

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  if (!answer) {
      answer = GlobalAnswer;
  }
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

  rl.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть [read_line](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) пакет

`npm i readline`

```js
(async()=>{
    const readline = require('readline');
    const rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});
    const key = await new Promise((r)=>{rl.question('Type: ', r)});
    console.log(key);
})();
```

Comment: Зачем `npm i`? Это же встроенный модуль.

Comment: Вопрос, можно ли записать key, в данном случае, в глобальную переменную, которая не будет использоваться именно в этой функции. Я имею ввиду вот такую конструкцию:  
`(async()=>{
    const readline = require('readline');
    const rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});
    const key = await new Promise((r)=>{rl.question('Type: ', r)});
})();

console.log(key);`

Comment: Что-то я комментарий неправильно написал. Так вот смысл в том, что функция console.log(key) находится за функцией readline и выдаёт ошибку при выводе. То есть переменная key существует только внутри данной функции.

Comment: @Yaant пусть рядышком лежит

Comment: @LaKeR omg, Дак делай с ней всё что хочешь, это пример куда копать, который закрывает твой вопрос в необходимости input. Ты берешь и записываешь в свою глобалку или хоть в ini файл, выбор за тобой и копать тебе, я просто дал лапату (кто ответственный, лмао)

Comment: @LaKeR с такими вопросами, ты бы сначала базу выучил, +прежде чем глобальные переменные таскать